# pandas agrregate and join dataframe during group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
id parentid score body
1   10        10  abc
2   10         0  xyz
3   10         1  efg 
4   23         3  afd
5   23         2  asfagr
6   34         1  wrqqw
```

i need to groupby(parentid) then aggregate score by mean , and join body. id field is not relevent, it can be changed to min or max.

result should be

```
id parentid score body
1   10         3  abc xyz efg
4   23         2  afd asfagr 
6   34         1  wrqqw
```

i have tried

```
def f(x):
    x['Id'] = x['Id']
    x['ParentId'] = x['ParentId']
    x['Score'] = x['Score'].min() #change to max/ min/ mean to get different results!
    x['Body']= " ".join(x['Body'])
    return x


temp = temp.groupby("ParentId").apply(f)
temp = temp.reset_index()
```

it gives corerct result but ince **dataset size is >1.8 gb** , the system becomes irresponsive.
i have tried it in google colab too, it has crashed 3 times.

please suggest a faster method such as lambda functions or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
temp.groupby("ParentId").agg({"score":np.mean, "body": lambda x: " ".join([I for I in x])})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using groupby with agg and a dictionary to define aggregations for each column:

```
df.groupby('parentid', as_index=False)[['score', 'body']]\
  .agg({'score':'mean', 'body':' '.join})
```

Output:

```
   parentid     score         body
0        10  3.666667  abc xyz efg
1        23  2.500000   afd asfagr
2        34  1.000000        wrqqw
```